# Save css on elements tab manually instead of automatically with Chrome Workspaces?

Tags: css, google-chrome, stylesheet, google-chrome-devtools

I just set up Chrome Workspaces but it's doing something that's really upsetting my workflow. If I edit a source file in the sources tab, it won't save it until I tell it to - this is good.  But if I edit a style in the elements tab, it automatically saves it without me telling it to.

I can see how some people would like this, but I like to experiment with styles a lot.  If I like my changes, I save them.  If I don't, I throw them out.  As it is, it automatically saves the changes the moment I do them, so I am constantly worried about screwing up my page and losing its original state.  I am no longer free to experiment without a fear of losing my original page.

Is there a way to configure Chrome so changes I make in the elements tab are not saved until I tell them to be saved?  Or perhaps is there an option to revert changes to their state when the webpage loaded? Is there some other solution for this?  How do you handle experimenting in Chrome?

Comment: Did you find a workaround? I have the same conundrum, I like the idea of automatic saves, but I need to be able to experiment safely as well.

Comment: @Mahn I'm afraid I moved on and looked at other workflows. This is not to say there is not a solution to this, especially after all this time - just that I moved on before finding one.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a bit old but wanted to pass along what i found and see if you have found any new info as well...

My work around has been to remove the network mapping from your workspace Scss or CSS files. Then you will still be able to go into Sources and edit all of your files and save them directly thorough Chrome but if you go to ELement.styles pane and play around with the styles there they will not be auto-saved and if you refresh the page things will be back to normal.

The only down side to this is, when editing code in the sources page when you make a change it will not auto reload you will have to manually reload the page. So there is a bit of a trade off there. If you are using some other kind of extension like LiveReload then this may not be an issue for you.

Currently I am using Chrome with network mapping most of the time and then if I want to play around i use chrome canary with no workspace or mapping set up so i can play around without issue.

Hope this helps, let me know if you found a better solution. Cheers,

Comment: This is not true, at least not in 2021-04.  It also autosaves in element Styles. It is really annoying. (I edit a local file (url) with local files (sources).)

Comment: @e-motiv this post was from 2014 and Workspaces were brand new.

Comment: And it still is relevant. Amazing, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Local modifications](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/authoring-development-workflow#local-modifications). It should do the job.

Comment: This seems like it would be a solution, but it doesn't seem to work - perhaps it's still buggy?  It sometimes shows revisions and sometimes it doesn't.  Even if it does show revisions, if I click to revert all changes, nothing happens at all and my changes stay.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Undo feature (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in the **Elements** panel will undo the last change, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> will redo the change undone last). The undo stack is deep enough to cover most use cases.